# adding images to wordpress pagination?

Tags: images, pagination, links

I'm working with a blank theme and my nav.php looks like this

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="next-posts" style="float: left;"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts" style="float: right;"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
```

My question is, how do I change the text links into image links?

Comment: What sort of image links?  Like just a standard image for each?  Or you want it pulled from the actual post?  If so, attached images, or featured image?

Comment: I have some buttons I want to use in place of the words "Older Entries" and "Newer Entries." So not ones pulled from the post, just standard images (ex/ http://blog.studentlife.uiowa.edu/svp/wp-content/themes/svp/images/prev.png)

Comment: Style them with CSS?

Comment: Explain further? I can make them background images but then how do I make them link?

There has to be something simpler than using a plugin

Comment: http://www.kinocreative.co.uk/hints-and-tips/wordpress-nextprevious-post-navigation-with-images-and-inactive-links/  seems to be a good writeup, you can just add the links in as variables to next/previous posts link

Comment: <div class="next-posts" style="float: left;"><?php previous_post_link('%link','<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/prev.png" />'); ?></div>
 <div class="prev-posts" style="float: right;"><?php next_post_link('%link','<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/next.png" />'); ?></div>



that's the code i used


which you can see here:
http://blog.studentlife.uiowa.edu/svp/

but it's not displaying all the entries

Comment: i finally got it to work. thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: @Maddy: It's great that you found the solution yourself. Can you add it as an answer here and mark it as "accepted"? That way others can benefit from it too.

Comment: it wont let me for whatever reason down there, but for whoever's interested:

<div class="next-posts" style="float: left;"><?php next_posts_link('<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/prev.png" />'); ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts" style="float: right;"><?php previous_posts_link('<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/next.png" />'); ?></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [my (edu) plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon) can help you understanding the ways that are possible to display pagination a little better.

I updated it after reading your Q. You can now more easily style your links. Just add your buttons as background-images to the stylesheet.